# Facebook API V4 (#100) The parameter input_token is required

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using Facebook Api V4. What I am doing is, I am posting text/link to facebook page. I also generated long lived access token. For that I am using Below code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('*****', '*****');

$session = new FacebookSession('*****');

// To validate the session:
try {
        $session->validate();
      $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'POST',
      '/183457781707540/feed',
      array (
        'message' => 'This is a test message',
        'link' =>  'http://images.speakingtree.iimg.in/files/04-2015/180363/c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710_1429705305.jpg'
      )
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
  echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
  // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

My main problem is this code works perfectly on my local PC. But when I upload this file to server then

```
$session->validate();
```

give me error called: `(#100) The parameter input_token is required`

I don't know what I am missing.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks.